# How to get a gasoline odor out of my shed?

Tags: gasoline

My shed reeks of Gasoline, (because, you know, it was used as a shed), I don't have a very large backyard, and so I'm happy using my push mower which doesn't use any Gasoline.

I'd like my Shed to double as a weight lifting and punching bag room, but I don't want to inhale Gasoline fumes while attempting to improve my health.

Is there any way to remove the smell and lower my risk of Gasoline inhalation?

Comment: I'm a bit concerned that there's a gasoline odor in the first place.  Something was leaking or not properly capped.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yeah, my mower; it’s capped though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the door(s) and window(s) if any, plug in a fan, wait.

Comment: Waiting is the key. It takes a long time for gasoline odors to dissipate. Depending on how much gas was spilled / leaked into the floor/concrete/soil, it could take months.

Comment: Yup. You could try and get fancy with an ozone generator or the like, but if more is seeping up from where it has soaked in (that the ozone would not get to), the effect of such a thing would only be temporary.

Comment: Almost certainly gonna need to scrub the floor to remove combustibles, let alone smelly stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to waiting, you can also try to remove some of the remnant and seal it.

Just some dish soap and warm water, wash down everything you can get to.

Paint everything you can to seal in what you can. Specifically look for a sealer, something that is intended to cover up stains. They tend to wick less stuff to the surface.

Comment: I'm no fan of paint as sealer.  If you're painting instead of cleaning, the new paint won't do what you want, and you'll have a real mess on your hands.  If you clean, you probably won't need to paint.